# Installed reFIT on Lion and now I can't login

Tags: macos, efi

I installed reFIT on my new MBP, and now, unfortunately, OSX can't get past the login screen. When I try logging in, it simply bounces me back to where I started, the login page.

Since I can't get in to OSX, I can't delete the `/efi` folder as recommended. Is there any way for me to fix this so I can at least get back into OSX to fix things?

Comment: Did you try single user mode ?

Answer (score 4):

If you **disable journaling** for the Macintosh partition (in order to access files from within Linux) this should work:

1. hold <kbd>⌥</kbd> upon boot
2. select **Recovery HD** OR boot from Mac install DVD/USB
3. open Disk Utility. Select Macintosh HD. Hold <kbd>⌥</kbd> and click on *File*. Select *Disable Journaling*.
4. boot from a Linux Live CD. Open root terminal.
5. delete `/Library/StartupItems/rEFItBlesser` on the Mac partition
6. delete `/efi` on the Mac partition

If journaling was already disabled on the Mac Partition, move to step 4.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### Start up in single-user mode and remove reFIT

1. Shut down your Mac if it is on.
2. Press the power button to start the computer.
3. Immediately press and hold <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for single-user mode.
4. At the prompt, type `/sbin/fsck -fy`

   - Press Enter or Return key to execute the command.
   - Text will start updating the progress...if there is damage, the final line will say ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****.
   - If you see that message, REPEAT step 4 until that message no longer appears. Having to run fsck more than once is normal, because the first run's repairs may uncover additional problems. 
     The end should read: "The volume  appears to be OK."
5. Mount your disk using `mount -uw /`
6. Move or delete `/Library/StartupItems/rEFItBlesser`
7. Move or delete `/efi`

Assembled from [Mac OS X: How to start up in single-user or verbose mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1492), [Booting in Single User Mode and Running fsck -fy](http://www.gballard.net/macrant/osx_troubleshooting.html#fsck) and [Matt's suggestion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/34483/14994)

Good luck.